# C signals are not caught in the same order they were sent (or not caught at all)

Tags: c, signals

I have two programs, one that receives signals and on that sends signals to the first one. I'm only using SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2 to do that and it doesn't catch the signals in the same order they were sent. I saw on some posts than SIGUSR2 is caught right when it's sent contrary to SIGUSR1, but I putted both signals in the sigaction mask, so they should be blocked while the handler is running. I wrote a minimal reproducible example to illustrate my problem:

Sender program (client):

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int ppid;

    if (argc != 2)
        return (-1);
    ppid = atoi(argv[1]);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2) {
            kill(ppid, SIGUSR1);
            printf("1\n");
        }
        else
        {
            kill(ppid, SIGUSR2);
            printf("2\n");
        }
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Catcher program (server):

```
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void    sig_handler(int sig)
{
    if (sig == SIGUSR1)
        printf("1\n");
    else if (sig == SIGUSR2)
        printf("2\n");
}

int main(void) {
    struct sigaction act;

    printf("%d\n", getpid());
    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
    sigaddset(&act.sa_mask, SIGUSR1);
    sigaddset(&act.sa_mask, SIGUSR2);
    act.sa_flags = 0;
    act.sa_handler = sig_handler;
    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &act, 0);
    sigaction(SIGUSR2, &act, 0);
    while (42)
        pause();
    return (0);
}
```

I start the server first to get its PID, then I run the client with the server's PIDas first argument and then I get on my client the output:

```
2
1
2
1
2
1
2
1
2
1
```

I expect it to be the same in the server, but instead I get:

```
2
1
1
1
2
2
1
2
1
```

Apparently there is a SIGUSR2 that hasn't been caught, and the signals are not received in the same order, what is the problem?

EDIT: I redid some tests and sometimes my program misses a bunch of signals and I get outputs like:

```
2
1
2
```

Comment: Trivial comment: you should not call printf() from a signal handler.

Comment: I'd find a better way to communicate than signals but you can _queue_ signals if you have POSIX realtime signals: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19048-01/chorus5/806-6897/architecture-123/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Do *not* call `printf` from your signal handler. Change your code as follows for better behavior.

```
void    sig_handler(int sig)
{
    if (sig == SIGUSR1)
        write(1, "1\n", 2);
    else if (sig == SIGUSR2)
        write(1, "2\n", 2);
}
```

This code is still wrong for the mistake of assuming `write` is going to write all the bytes at once. It won't always do so so you might lose some newlines but the behavior will be more obvious than before. But you will still see out-of-order writes.

The reason this doesn't work correctly is signals can and will be received while handling signals. `print` is not re-entrant so arbitrary badness happens. Lots of trivial examples call `printf` in signal handlers because they either know or assume it's safe and most real use cases get away with it because the actual conflict is rare, but you made it common by sending signals in a tight loop.

In addition, there is no real guarantee that signals are received in the order sent either.

Answer (score 1):

> Apparently there is a SIGUSR2 that hasn't been caught, and the signals are not received in the same order, what is the problem?

There's no problem. Signals have never provided a guarantee that they will get caught in the order they are sent. There is also no guarantee that sending more than one instance of a signal will result in more than one instance of that signal being caught.

All that is guaranteed is that if you send a particular signal, that same signal will be received. If you sent SIGUSR2 twice and then a single SIGUSR2 is received, then in both cases, the same signal was received.

In typical implementations, every process has a "yes/no" flag for each signal. Sending the signal sets that flag to "yes" and receiving the signal sets it to "no". Sending SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2 in either order just results in both the SIGUSR1 and SIGUSR2 flags being set to "yes". If a flag is already set to "yes", sending the signal has no effect.

It sounds like you are using signals for some purpose other than signaling, and that's not a good idea. Use a socket, pipe, regular file, shared memory, or something else instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the thing is that's a homework and we are only allowed to use signals to communicate through processes, so the only way of doing that would be to sleep between each `kill` if I understood well how signals works?

Comment: @Fayeure: There comes a time to consider when the homework assignment is just bad. Signals simply aren't designed for rapid-fire communication.

Comment: @Joshua There's probably some better way to do what the assignment asks you to do. For example, you could have each signal be acknowledged with a signal.